# How can I add Tags to my blog while creating a new post?

Tags: c#, tags

I am trying to figure out how to insert a list of tag objects while creating a new Post.

```
    public class Post
    {
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
    }
     public class PostTag
    {
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set;}
     }
    public class Tag
    {
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PostTag> PostTags { get; set }
```

// PostController

Content = model.Content, I can't figure out how to get the tags Do I use Tags, PostTags? I'm so confused.

```
public IActionResult Add(NewPostModel model)
{
    return new Post()
    {
    Title = model.Title,

    Tags = ??
    }
}
```

Comment: This depends on if you are using an ORM like Entity Framework or not. Sometimes it will be simple as adding a collection of Tags to the post while your ORM does all of the relationship management. If you are managing the relationships manually, then you'll need to create new PostTags and Tags along with the Post.

Comment: I am using Entity Framework Core (2.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use object initializer syntax :

```
public IActionResult Add(NewPostModel model)
{
    return new Post()
    {
        Title = model.Title,

        PostTags = new List<PostTag> ()
        {
            new PostTag ()
            {
                Tag = new Tag ()
            },
            new PostTag ()
            {
                Tag = new Tag()
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

You can find more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers)

Comment: Good idea, except what if I wanted to use "string.split" to seperate multiple tags as well?